# Does template instantiate multiple times for same type of parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is my code to explain the question:

```
template<typename T>
void get_data(T data)
{
    cout << "got me" << data << endl;
}

int main()
{
      get_data(10);
      get_data(20);
}
```

Here in this piece of code when `get_data(20)` will be called, there would be already a code extension for `int` when `get_data(10)` called. So again it will extend the code for same data type or will it use the extended one?
Please explain.

Comment: It will be instatiated once per type: `get_data<int>(...)`, `get_data<double>(...)`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Instantiation will be single in the same compilation unit. Besides being wasteful, double template instantiation with the same types will cause a violation of ODR (one definition rule) - if you have 2 identical functions, how would you (or compiler) know which one to use each time?

For different compilation units, it's possible that template will be instantiated independently in each unit. During linkage stage one of the implementations will be dropped (or alternatively, cause a linkage error, depends on the linker and its configuration).

Comment: Thanks!! Just curious to know, if that is the case how template cause the code bloat?? Because a function overloading also will do same kind of work here and we never face code bloat for the same. Any thoughts here?

Comment: Templates don't cause any more code bloat than function overloading per se. It's just more transparent to programmers with templates since you don't actually keep manually copying the code for each overloaded version.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are expanded during compile time to include the variants needed. In this case it will only need to build an `int` version of the `get_data` function and it will be used for both calls.